# Entropy of $f^{m(x)+n}$ of full shift

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, it.information-theory, entropy

Let $(X,\mu,f)$ be a two-sided full shift system. Assume that there is $t \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in X$, we can define $T(x)=f^{n+m(x)}(x)$, where $m(x) \leq t; $ $m(x) \in \mathbb{N}$ and that depends on $x$. I also assume that $T$ is measure preserving.

It is well-known that $h_{\mu}(f^n)=nh_{\mu}(f)$, where $h_{\mu}$ is the measure-theoretic entropy.

Can we use the above fact to say $h_{\mu}(T) \leq (n+t)h_{\mu}(f)$?

Edit: As it was mentioned in comments, $T$ is not necessarily measure preserving. I add the assumption that $T$ is measure preserving.

Comment: To begin with, your new transformation  need not be measure preserving.

Comment: @RW Thanks for your comment. Even, isn't it a measure preserving when $(X, \mu, f)$ is a full shift?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @VilleSalo Natural numbers

Comment: Is $0$ a natural number? (Sorry, I tried to be concise.)

Comment: @VilleSalo No, it is not! Feel free to ask any questions

Comment: @Adam $T$ need not preserve even the uniform product measure on the binary full shift $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z}$. Namely, for $n=1$ and $m(x)=1+x_3$ we have $T(x)_0=0$ iff $x_2=x_3=0$, which has probability $1/4$ instead of $1/2$.

Comment: @IlkkaTörmä. Thanks for your example. One more question: assume there is a finite set of natural numbers; let's call $S$. We define $T(x)=f^{m(x)+n}(x)$, where $m(x) \in S.$ Again, isn't it preserving?

Comment: @IlkkaTörmä The reason that I asked questions is: I have a preserving function like $T$, where it is some iteration of $f$, and I want to see whether the above entropy relation holds or not. Unfortunately, I can not exactly write the function as it is so complicated, but I knew $f$, which is some iteration of $T$ is preserving.

Comment: @Adam In my example we have $S=\{1,2\}$. Anyway, if you know $T$ to be measure-preserving, then it would be a good idea to add that as an assumption to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand right, your function $m$ (for a fixed $n$) takes on only finitely many values, which are all measurable sets. You can then define the partition $\{m^{-1}(i)\}$ and the associated finite $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$.

If we define $\mathcal{A}$ to be any finite sub-$\sigma$-algebra of your original $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets, then it's well-known (Corollary 4.10 of Walters) that $k^{-1} H_\mu\left(\bigvee_{i=0}^{k-1} T^{-i} \mathcal{A} \right)$ converges (in fact decreases) to $h_\mu(T, \mathcal{A})$.

In your case, I think by definition $\bigvee_{i = 0}^k T^{-i} \mathcal{A}$ is contained in
$\bigvee_{i = 0}^{k(n+t)-1} f^{-i} (\mathcal{A} \vee \mathcal{B})$. Therefore,
$k^{-1} H_\mu\left(\bigvee_{i=0}^{k-1} T^{-i} \mathcal{A} \right)
\leq k^{-1} H_\mu\left(\bigvee_{i = 0}^{k(n+t)-1} f^{-i} (\mathcal{A} \vee \mathcal{B}) \right) = (n+t) (k(n+t))^{-1} H_\mu\left(\bigvee_{i = 0}^{k(n+t)-1} f^{-i} (\mathcal{A} \vee \mathcal{B}) \right).$

But by the above, the first quantity approaches $h_\mu(T, \mathcal{A})$ and the final quantity approaches $(n+t) h_\mu(f, \mathcal{A} \vee \mathcal{B})$. Therefore, $h_\mu(T, \mathcal{A}) \leq (n+t) h_\mu(f, \mathcal{A} \vee \mathcal{B})$, and then taking the supremum over $\mathcal{A}$ yields $h_\mu(T) \leq (n+t) h_\mu(f)$.